# How to use redux in react native class Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
         let dharadata = this.state.new_item;//all product data to share 
 dharadata
          consolepro.consolelog("product data", dharadata)
          //const dispatch = useDispatch();

          // const { dispatch } = this.props;
          // dispatch(getDataMethod(dharadata));
          // const getDataMethod = this.props.getDataMethod;
          // consolepro.consolelog("redux data", getDataMethod)
          this.props.getData(dharadata)
          consolepro.consolelog("redux data", this.props.data)
```

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.getDataMethod
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
   getDataMethod
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeTicket);
```

```
Reducers.js

import { ADD_ITEM, REMOVE_ITEM,GET_ALL_ITEM } from '../redux/ActionTypes'

export const Reducers = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_ITEM:
            return [...state, action.payload];

        case REMOVE_ITEM:
            const deleteArray = state.filter((item, index) => {
                return index !== action.payload;
            });
            return deleteArray;

        case GET_ALL_ITEM:
            return [...state];

        default:
            return [...state];
    }
};
```

```
store.js

import { createStore } from "redux"
import { Reducers } from '../redux/Reducers';

export const mystore=createStore(Reducers);
```

```
action.js

import { ADD_ITEM, REMOVE_ITEM,GET_ALL_ITEM } from "../redux/ActionTypes";


export const addItemToCart = data => ({
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload: data,
});


export const removeItemToCart = index => ({
    type: REMOVE_ITEM,
    payload: index,
});


export const getDataMethod = obj => ({
    type: GET_ALL_ITEM,
    payload: obj,
});
import { ADD_ITEM, REMOVE_ITEM,GET_ALL_ITEM } from "../redux/ActionTypes";


export const addItemToCart = data => ({
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload: data,
});


export const removeItemToCart = index => ({
    type: REMOVE_ITEM,
    payload: index,
});


export const getDataMethod = obj => ({
    type: GET_ALL_ITEM,
    payload: obj,
});
```

```
actiontype.js

export const ADD_ITEM = "ADD_ITEM";
export const REMOVE_ITEM = "REMOVE_ITEM";
export const GET_ALL_ITEM = "GET_ALL_ITEM";
```

This is my code:

- `dharadata` variable gives me full data I want to send this data to store
- I'm using the `connect` Higher Order Component in the class component but I don't know where is my error
- Properly I don't know how to do this but I can try to send data to a store but it gave me an error
- error like this
- data not come it's give me like Undefined

  ```
  LOG  err [TypeError: _getDataMethod is not a function. (In 
  '_getDataMethod(dharadata)', '_getDataMethod' is undefined)]
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've named both the state you are selecting ***and*** the action you want to dispatch `getDataMethod`. Give the state and action different names.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state // <-- data is just the state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getDataMethod
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeTicket);
```

Don't forget that the actions passed in the second argument to the `connect` Higher Order Component are automatically wrapped in a call to `dispatch`, so there is no reason to do so again in the component.

Access the selected state via `this.props.data`, and access the action via `this.props.getDataMethod`.

```
const dharadata = this.state.new_item;
consolepro.consolelog("data", dharadata);
```

```
// Instead of this
// const { dispatch, getDataMethod } = this.props;
// dispatch(getDataMethod(dharadata));

// Do this
this.props.getDataMethod(dharadata); // <-- already wrapped in dispatch!
```

```
consolepro.consolelog("redux data", this.props.data);
```

Comment: It's not give me data it's give me  "redux data undefined" like this

Comment: @GattuPatel Sorry, can you clarify that comment? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: consolepro.consolelog("redux data", this.props.data); this line give me "redux data undefined"

Comment: data not come in this.props.data so where is mistake

Comment: @GattuPatel Then either the `state.getDataMethod` that you are selecting is undefined, or you may've missed renaming it to `data` in the `mapStateToProps` function. I'll be honest, `getDataMethod` is an *odd* name for a slice of state. "State" is usually an object and get named as nouns, but you've named something with a verb, which is usually a function to do an "action", i.e. do something. In other words, it *might* just be that `state.getDataMethod` ***is*** undefined because it's a mistake. Can you [edit] the post to include your `combineReducers` and store creation?

Comment: I can edit my post with store file and reducers file ?

Comment: @GattuPatel Yes, please, that would be helpful.

Comment: yes I can add now check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250600/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-gattu-patel).

Comment: please here change mapDispatchToProps like I send in chat box so  this will help to others

Comment: @GattuPatel I think I already have, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yesh you mistaken here......
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getDataMethod
};

Comment: @GattuPatel I see. I just renamed it as `getData` and accessed it as `this.props.getData` in the component. You can choose to rename it or not.

Comment: yes sure I'm edit my example